# how to insert two form fields into one column using php in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to take two variables from two different fields of a form and insert into one column... but can't understand how to do?? here is what i've tried..

```
$name= $_GET['name'];
$age = $_GET['age'];
$sex = $_GET['sex'];
$wpm = $_GET['wpm'];   
$query = "INSERT INTO ajax_example (name,age,sex,wpm) values ('$name','$age','$sex','$wpm.$age')";
```

I want the combination of age and wpm to be stored in wpm

Comment: concatenate **first** then assign a new variable to the ones you want to be combined.

Comment: This should do the work `$query = "INSERT INTO ajax_example (name,age,sex,wpm) values ('name','age','sex','{$wpm}{$age}')";`

Comment: `$query = "INSERT INTO ajax_example (name, age, sex, wpm) values ('$name', '$age', '$sex', '".$wpm.$age."')";`

Answer (score 0):

You can just join the strings first:

```
$col = $wpm.$age;
$query = "INSERT INTO ajax_example (name,age,sex,wpm) values ('$name','$age','$sex','$col')";
```

Notice that using the code like this is very dangerous - [SQL injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Comment: it's not working i've tried it..
i think i shouldn't store this value and concatenate in echo...

Comment: The only way it will not work is if wpm field length is set to a length that can only conatin $wpm value. for example if it is varchar(3) and the length of $wpm is 3 and $age is 2, than only the first 3 characters from the concatenate string will be store, and those equals to $wpm value.